# MMC Snap-in, mail and proxyaddress without exchange

Tags: active-directory, exchange

We are migrating from Exchange to Google Apps. We are using mail and proxyaddress fields in AD to populate information in Google Apps. We need to have access to those fields via MMC Snap-in after we decommission MS-Exchange. Active Directory will still be the primary system for adding and editing accounts going forward (using GADS).

How can we have access to the mail and proxyaddress field in the MMC without exchange? In case we use the Exchange snap-in, will it throw a error because exchange won't be there?

Answer (score 1):

Those "fields" are just Active Directory attributes, so you can use whatever can interface with and edit Active Directory attributes.  [ADSI Edit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773354%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) is a graphical utility that comes with Windows, or you could use LDAP queries or PowerShell... or, really, whatever you're most comfortable manipulating AD objects and attributes with.